# Not able to get output in complex auto mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, automapper

I have three database entity tables Roles, Features, RoleFeatures

```
`Public class Roles
{
        public long RoleIdPk { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription{ get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy{ get; set; }
}
Public class Features
{
        public long FeatureIDPk{ get; set; }
        public string FeatureName{ get; set; }
        public string FeatureDescription{ get; set; }
        public int CreatedBy{ get; set; }
}
Public class RoleFeatures
{
        public long RoleIDFk{ get; set; }
        public long FeatureIDFk{ get; set; }
        public string ViewPermission{ get; set; }
        public string addPermission{ get; set; }
        public stringEditPermission{ get; set; }
        public string DeletePermission{ get; set; }
}`
```

And i want to get an output like
In all GetAllRoles API I want output of

```
    `"status": "true",
    "data": {
“roles”:[
{                       "roleId": "number",
            "roleName": "string",
            "features":[
            {
            “featureId”:”number”,
            “featureName”:”string”,
            "view": "string",
                        "add": "string",
            "edit": "string",
            "delete": "string"
            },
            {
            “featureId”:”number”,
            “featureName”:”string”,
            "view": "string",
                        "add": "string",
            "edit": "string",
            "delete": "string"
            },  
            ]
            }
}`
```

```
    public class GetRolesResponse : FeaturesDTO
    {
        public long RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
       public List<FeaturesDTO> Features { get; set; }
    }
    public class FeaturesDTO 
    {
        public long FeatureId { get; set; }
        public string FeatureName { get; set; }
        public bool ViewPerm { get; set; }
        public bool AddPerm { get; set; }
        public bool EditPerm { get; set; }
        public bool DeletePerm { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Mapping of role
 `CreateMap<Roles, GetRolesResponse>();`
`

> List roles1 = _mapper.Map<List>(roles);`

GeallRoles Query

`List<Role>roles = await _context.Roles.ToListAsync();`

but im not getting array of features table in getall method of roles.
Im only getting RoleDTO with values.
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Roles` model does not have a corresponding `List` that matches the `Features` in `GetRolesResponse`, so `Features` will be null.

Can you change the model structure of `RoleFeatures` and `FeaturesDTO` so that the two match? If you can, it will be very simple. Here is an example:

Models:

```
public class Roles
{
    [Key]
    public long RoleIdPk { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public List<RoleFeatures> RoleFeatures { get; set; }
}

public class Features
{
    [Key]
    public long FeatureIDPk { get; set; }
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string FeatureDescription { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
public class RoleFeatures
{
    public long RoleIDFk { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public long FeatureIDFk { get; set; }
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string ViewPermission { get; set; }
    public string addPermission { get; set; }
    public string EditPermission{ get; set; }
    public string DeletePermission { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleIDFk")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Roles Roles { get; set; }
}


public class GetRolesResponse
{
    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<FeaturesDTO> Features { get; set; }
}
public class FeaturesDTO
{
    public long FeatureId { get; set; }
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string ViewPerm { get; set; }
    public string AddPerm { get; set; }
    public string EditPerm { get; set; }
    public string DeletePerm { get; set; }
}
```

Profile:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Roles, GetRolesResponse>()
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.RoleId,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RoleIdPk))
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.Features,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.RoleFeatures));

        CreateMap<RoleFeatures, FeaturesDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.FeatureId,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FeatureIDFk))
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.ViewPerm,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ViewPermission))
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.EditPerm,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EditPermission))
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.AddPerm,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.addPermission))
            .ForMember(dest =>
                dest.DeletePerm,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeletePermission));
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<List<GetRolesResponse>> IndexAsync()
{
    List<Roles> roles = await _context.Roles.Include(r => r.RoleFeatures).ToListAsync();
    var roles1 = _mapper.Map<List<GetRolesResponse>>(roles);
    return roles1;
}
```

Test Result:

[image]